# How to detect CMake project loading in a Visual Studio Extension (VSIX)

Tags: c#, cmake, visual-studio-extensions, vsix, vspackage

I need to extend the functionality of my VS Extension and I need to execute some actions when a CMake project is loading. The problem is the `InitializeAsync` method which is not automatically called when a CMake project is loading. When a .sln file is loading the `InitializeAsync` method is called automatically and I can configure the extension setup.

My question is:
How can I detect when a CMake project is loading and trigger the `InitializeAsync` method to activate my extension?

Comment: Have you tried [IVsSolutionEvents.OnAfterLoadProject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivssolutionevents.onafterloadproject?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) or [IVsSolutionEvents.OnAfterOpenProject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivssolutionevents.onafteropenproject?view=visualstudiosdk-2017)? You can check if it will be fired when loading or opening Cmake project.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I already use IVsSolutionEvents in my project but my problem is: The `InitializeAsync` method is called when the VS is starting or when I load a CMake project. My code actually doesn't run. Everything is ok when I am loading a regular `.sln` file. I think this is because the CMake project it's like an open folder project and VS treats it differently. Do you know how to handle this particular behavior?